# Is there an error on the Google Glass LiveCard sample code on the Developer Guides?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I was going through the GDK docs on [`LiveCards`](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards#creating_high-frequency_live_cards) (high frequency) and I came across this line of code:

```
mLiveCard.getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(new RenderThread());
```

`RenderThread` is a `Class` that `extends` `Thread` and does not implement any `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. In the other hand, in the same sample code they define `LiveCardRenderer` which implements `DirectRenderingCallback` which in turn `extends` `SurfaceHolder.Callback`. Shouldn't `LiveCardRenderer` be used instead of `RenderThread`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for catching that. You're right, it should be `new LiveCardRenderer()`. The documentation has now been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This does look a lot like a mistake, as you rightly say, instead of `new RenderThread()`, you should have `new LiveCardRenderer()`.

If you take a look and any of the sample apps in the GDK, for example the compass app you can see they have something like

```
mRenderer = new CompassRenderer(this, mOrientationManager, mLandmarks);
mLiveCard.setDirectRenderingEnabled(true).getSurfaceHolder().addCallback(mRenderer);
```

Where `CompassRenderer` extends `SurfaceHolder.Callback` as you would expect and the code is similar in principle to that given for `LiveCardRenderer`.

I hope that helps.